# Why doesn't my videos stay in the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

When ever I do nothing to it my box/border stays around it but when I write float: left; it goes out of the box/border perimeter how do i keep it in.

sorry cant post an image need more rep.

```
<div style="float: left; margin: 5px;"><embed width="220" height="145" src="youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"; type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div> <div style="float: left; margin: 5px;"><embed width="220" height="145" src="youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"; type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>
```

Comment: first of all `float` property doesn't have `center` value. second can't you reproduce a simple DEMO.

Comment: What's your position? Fixed, absolute? What about display? If you could clarify that would be helpful.

Comment: <div style="float: left; margin: 5px;"><embed width="220" height="145"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>
        <div style="float: left; margin: 5px;"><embed width="220" height="145"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>

Comment: .inner-border {    position: relative;} .inner-border:before { position: Absolute; }

Comment: produce a jsfiddle and explain what u want exactly ?

Comment: @Nub it would be good if you put your code on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

See there is no center property for float in css, there are just three as:

```
float: left | right | none;
```

---

*When ever I do Float: Center; my box/border stays around it but when I write float: left; it goes out of the box/border perimeter how do i keep it in.*

change the css little bit:

```
float: left; padding:5px; margin-right: 5px;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8NZYU/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is nothing of sort as float:center , its either float:left or float:right

Secondly, try setting up your code something like this:

```
<div class="videobox">

  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

</div>
```

Now you should apply styles to the .videobox class only.this way your video would remain inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

> When ever I do Float: Center; my box/border stays around it

Because there is no center value for float and the browser takes it as initial value i.e. `float:initial`

if initial is supported by browser else it takes nothing for float i.e. float is not rendered by the browser.

---

If you give float to the divs then you have to clear its parent, for easier I would apply `overflow:hidden;` to the parent div.

Comment: That one worked and sorry about float: center; still learning ;)